# Firebase auth. Google + Facebook = Crash

Tags: ios, firebase, facebook-login, firebase-authentication, swift3

I've successfully implemented Google Sign in iOS version of my app (Google + Twitter + Facebook in Android version working too). Now I'm trying to add FB login, but it seems to have conflict with Google sign in. After I see successful FB login screen in WebView and press OK - app crashes.

```
Error Domain=com.google.GIDSignIn Code=-4 "(null)"
2016-09-01 18:51:55.745 APP_NAME[4574:] <FIRAnalytics/INFO> Firebase Analytics enabled
2016-09-01 18:52:10.039 APP_NAME[4574:3352620] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:/" - error: "(null)"
2016-09-01 18:52:10.075 APP_NAME[4574:3352620] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:/" - error: "(null)"
(lldb) bt
* thread #1: tid = 0x33282c, 0x014dbd54 libswiftCore.dylib`swift::_swift_getClass(void const*), queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)
    frame #0: 0x014dbd54 libswiftCore.dylib`swift::_swift_getClass(void const*)
    frame #1: 0x014d2e62 libswiftCore.dylib`swift_getObjectType + 8
    frame #2: 0x0013dba0 APP_NAME`@objc AppDelegate.application(UIApplication, open : URL, sourceApplication : String?, annotation : Any) -> Bool + 328 at AppDelegate.swift:0
    frame #3: 0x001e8046 APP_NAME`-[FIRAAppDelegateProxy application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:] + 150
    frame #4: 0x258f214a UIKit`__45-[UIApplication _applicationOpenURL:payload:]_block_invoke + 906
    frame #5: 0x258f1c1a UIKit`-[UIApplication _applicationOpenURL:payload:] + 546
    frame #6: 0x258f9e8a UIKit`-[UIApplication _handleNonLaunchSpecificActions:forScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 3658
    frame #7: 0x258fe986 UIKit`__88-[UIApplication _handleApplicationLifecycleEventWithScene:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 174
    frame #8: 0x258fe898 UIKit`-[UIApplication _handleApplicationLifecycleEventWithScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 396
    frame #9: 0x258ea472 UIKit`__70-[UIApplication scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 134
    frame #10: 0x258ea160 UIKit`-[UIApplication scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 644
    frame #11: 0x2271cc28 FrontBoardServices`__80-[FBSSceneImpl updater:didUpdateSettings:withDiff:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke_2 + 40
    frame #12: 0x22737bf6 FrontBoardServices`__FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 18
    frame #13: 0x22737aa6 FrontBoardServices`-[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 226
    frame #14: 0x22737da4 FrontBoardServices`-[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 44
    frame #15: 0x2102b9e6 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 14
    frame #16: 0x2102b5d6 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 454
    frame #17: 0x2102993e CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 806
    frame #18: 0x20f781c8 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 516
    frame #19: 0x20f77fbc CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 108
    frame #20: 0x22594af8 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 160
    frame #21: 0x256b1434 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 144
  * frame #22: 0x001439a0 APP_NAME`main + 172 at AppDelegate.swift:12
    frame #23: 0x20c24872 libdyld.dylib`start + 2
```

Code from AppDelegate

```
@available(iOS 9.0, *)
    func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     open url: URL, options: [String: Any]) -> Bool {
        print(url)
        print(options)
        return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url as URL!,
                                                     sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication.rawValue] as? String,
                                                     annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation.rawValue])
                || FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, open: url,
                                                                         sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication.rawValue] as? String,
                                                                         annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation.rawValue])
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
        return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url as URL!, sourceApplication: sourceApplication!, annotation: annotation)
                || FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, open: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
    }
```

Comment: Just checked. Google sign in now don't work too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was caused by Apple "innovations". With Xcode 8 beta 6 I must use

```
@available(iOS 9.0, *)
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
```

Comment: I just started building with XCode 9.3 (9E145), and this issue never happened for me until this XCode version for some reason.  If anyone is searching and has XCode9.3, this answer fixes it.